# cannot install chrome extension in chromium on alpine Linux by preferences file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, alpine-linux

I am looking for ways to install chrome extension for chromium on alpine Linux automatically. Following https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/distribute/install-extensions, I put jndedldphmdenjgpepkjknihelibbpem.json to /opt/google/chrome/extensions/, /usr/share/google-chrome/extensions/, /opt/google/chromium/extensions/ and /usr/share/chromium/extensions/. I also put jndedldphmdenjgpepkjknihelibbpem.crx to /home/alpine. When I start chromium and go to chrome://extensions, my extension is not loaded. However if I manually drag my crx to extension page, it installs successfully.

```
jndedldphmdenjgpepkjknihelibbpem.json:
{ "external_crx": "/home/alpine/jndedldphmdenjgpepkjknihelibbpem.crx", "external_version": "1.0.0" }
```

```
manifest.json of my extension:
{
  "name": "myext",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon-16.png",
    "48": "icon-48.png",
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "description": "myext",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/inject.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/*"
  ]
}
```